# Schedule multiple notifications at fixed date and time?

Tags: android, calendar, notifications, alarmmanager, reminders

I have to display some notifications from my app on fixed date and time which is selected by the user which are sort of reminder.

It can be done using the ALARMMANAGER by android. I am not able to find any example or code to set the alarm on the desired date.

Or if I can add and remove an event to the calendar.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement service that will be responsible for the scheduling 
[Schedule Notification after some time](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/)

the link above shows you how to do that along with that you can use Timer Class of Android.description of which is here [Timer Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)